# jquery sorting json object

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I have the below Json object in jquery which i m using to fill a jquery grid.

Now i need to sort it on the basis of "performanceName".

Please advice how i can achieve this. Please i knw same kinda question is posted 100 times but still i m struggling to implement sorting on below json

```
{
    "callback": "",
    "html": "",
    "message": [
        ""
    ],
    "responseData": [
        {
            "collectionTitleId": 1107861,
            "collectionTitleIdSpecified": true,
            "performanceField": {
                "addedDate": "6/16/2011 11:11:10 PM",
                "artist": "Corbis",
                "performanceName": "Showcase Graphic 003 - Anime Girl Purple",
                "performanceType": "Graphic",
                "provider": "DMSP Dynamic Digital"
            },
            "sortOrder": "01"
        },
        {
            "collectionTitleId": 1113513,
            "collectionTitleIdSpecified": true,
            "performanceField": {
                "addedDate": "5/25/2011 9:27:39 AM",
                "artist": "Beloved",
                "performanceName": "Hating On Your Feet (Verse)",
                "performanceType": "LabelTone",
                "provider": "p1"
            },
            "sortOrder": "02"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        "Success"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.sort` to in-place sort an array.  Without any arguments, this attempts to sort elements alphabetically, but you can pass in a comparing function instead.  This function receives two arguments and should return less than 0, 0 or greater than 0 to define where argument 1 should be in relation to argument 2.

Your sorting function should look something like this:

```
data.responseData.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.performanceField.performanceName,
    b = b.performanceField.performanceName;

    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/aC5z4/**

`localeCompare` does the hard work of comparing the strings for us.

- [`sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`localeCompare` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: also dont forget to assign the sorted value back to original value.

Comment: @sathis: JavaScript's sort is an in-place sort, so no assignment is necessary.

Comment: I like localeCompare! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [
    { 'myKey': 'Ankit', 'status': 0 },    
    { 'myKey': 'Bhavik', 'status': 3 },
    { 'myKey': 'Parth', 'status': 7 },
    { 'myKey': 'Amin', 'status': 9 },
    { 'myKey': 'Russ', 'status': 9 },
    { 'myKey': 'Pete', 'status': 10 },
    { 'myKey': 'Ravi', 'status': 2 },
    { 'myKey': 'Tejas', 'status': 2 },
    { 'myKey': 'Dilip', 'status': 1 },
    { 'myKey': 'Piyush', 'status': 12 }
];
alert("0. At start: " + JSON.stringify(people));

//META.fn: sortData
jQuery.fn.sortData = function (prop, asc) {
        return this.sort(function (a, b) {           
            var x = a[prop];
        var y = b[prop];
            var retrunStatus = ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
            return (asc==undefined || asc) ? (retrunStatus * -1) : retrunStatus ;        
        });
    }

people2 = $(people).sortData('myKey',false);
alert("1. After sorting (0 to x): " + JSON.stringify(people2));
```